# Can a NTP Server escape the falseticker status?

Tags: ntp

I have 2 ntp server syncing to their local clock, the first one is a stratum 1 and the second is a stratum 7. The client is polling both of them and don't have a local clock as backup.

My ntp results are the following (view from the client) :

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*192.168.1.5     .GPS.            1 l    1    32  377    1.492   -0.107   0.249
+192.168.1.6     LOCL            8 l    1    32  377    1.369   183.293  0.249
```

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
x192.168.1.5     .GPS.            1 l    1    32  377    1.383   -0.135   0.120
x192.168.1.6     LOCL            8 l    1    32  377    1.3677  183.231  0.122
```

I know in my case that the difference between the offsets are very big. I am just testing things, theses servers won't be used.

If a server is declared as a falseticker by the client, can the status be reconsidered ? Or is the server sentenced to stay falseticker ?

I know after a restart of the ntp service on the client, the server status will be refreshed. But can it happen without restarting ntp on the client ?

Comment: People would need more information to answer your question.  How many upstream NTP servers are you syncing to, what stratum are they, what does your configuration look like?   What does `ntpq -pn` look like?

Comment: I edited the question to add context on my configuration, but i just want to know how falseticker status work in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTP falsetickers are statistical outliers in the last few time stamps. The status can change when the algorithms evaluate new data. You don't have the 4+ NTP servers required to reliably detect falsetickers. That may not be a problem if you don't have demanding requirements, could just use one decent performing NTP server.

Pay attention to the magnitude of the statistics. An offset of 180 ms is enormous when error from delay and jitter is single digit ms.

`192.168.1.6`  with refid  `LOCL` is a little unusual. [Undisciplined local clock](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/UndisciplinedLocalClock) pointing to self should not be used.    But usually the `LOCL` driver is invoked with config lines matching  `server 127.127.1`.  Is that a remote NTP server? If remote, and you are overriding the `refid` string in ntpd.conf, don't.

On some lightly loaded host, configure ntpd or chrony to add additional references from internet sources. As a test, although a diverse source list is a great start if you wanted to build stratum 2
NTP servers.

```
server 192.168.1.5 iburst
server 192.168.1.6 iburst
pool 2.pool.ntp.org iburst
server time.cloudflare.com iburst
server time.facebook.com iburst
```

Anything flagged as a falseticker in this local plus internet configuration likely is a real outlier.

Your NTP servers on the LAN should be very close to each other, better than 10 ms. They should reference each other. For example, configure the .6 appliance to reference .5 as a NTP source, and vice versa.

Comment: Actually, both servers are synced to their local clock, and I changed the refid of the `192.168.1.5` to display `GPS`. I stopped ntp on one of the server and the client selected the other, so it escaped the falseticker status. After that, I synced my servers to each other and now they have a small offset difference, my client is no longer tagging them as falseticker. Thanks for all theses informations.

Comment: My concern was that the hosts were 180 ms apart and you didn't say if the NTP servers were disciplined from something. General purpose computers have garbage clocks compared to a GNSS device (like GPS) or even NTP over the internet. Now that they reference each other, they will be close. Although 2 servers is not enough to actually detect a false ticker.

Comment: My 2 servers are 2 VM on a normal laptop so i suppose the offset come from this. After syncing both server to each other, i can achieve a minimum offset of 0.004ms and i go around 0.060ms, so it's way better than before. My client no longer see them as falseticker (for now).